# Duplicate ContextMenu MenuItem's in ObservableCollection DependancyProperty in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For some reason I have duplicate context menu items when I reuse my usercontrol even though I have only specified 1 menuitem.

For example Test 1 and Test 2 menuitems appear in both usercontrols even though they are coded in separate usercontrols.

My MainWindow looks like

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:OptionsMenu Grid.Row="0" MenuWidth="23" MenuHeight="7">
            <local:OptionsMenu.MenuItems>
                <MenuItem Header="Test 1"/>
            </local:OptionsMenu.MenuItems>
        </local:OptionsMenu>

        <local:OptionsMenu Grid.Row="1" MenuWidth="23" MenuHeight="7">
            <local:OptionsMenu.MenuItems>
                <MenuItem Header="Test 2"/>
            </local:OptionsMenu.MenuItems>
        </local:OptionsMenu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My UserControl looks like

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MenuButton">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Canvas>
                            <Path Data="M12.5,6.5 C12.5,9.8137085 9.8137085,12.5 6.5,12.5 C3.1862915,12.5 0.5,9.8137085 0.5,6.5 C0.5,3.1862915 3.1862915,0.5 6.5,0.5 C9.8137085,0.5 12.5,3.1862915 12.5,6.5 z M30.5,6.5 C30.5,9.8137085 27.813708,12.5 24.5,12.5 C21.186292,12.5 18.5,9.8137085 18.5,6.5 C18.5,3.1862915 21.186292,0.5 24.5,0.5 C27.813708,0.5 30.5,3.1862915 30.5,6.5 z M48.5,6.5 C48.5,9.8137085 45.813708,12.5 42.5,12.5 C39.186292,12.5 36.5,9.8137085 36.5,6.5 C36.5,3.1862915 39.186292,0.5 42.5,0.5 C45.813708,0.5 48.5,3.1862915 48.5,6.5 z" 
                                    Fill="Black" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                    Stretch="Fill" 
                                    Stroke="Black"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                    Height="{Binding MenuHeight}" 
                                    Width="{Binding MenuWidth}" />
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Canvas>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Root" Style="{DynamicResource MenuButton}" Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.ContextMenu >
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" />
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind

```
public ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> MenuItems
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>)GetValue(MenuItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MenuItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        internal static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MenuItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>), typeof(OptionsMenu),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>()));
```

Comment: Can you show us whole XAMLs ?

Comment: I've updated my XAMLs

Comment: Besides what's explained in the answer, it's unclear why you think you need to use ObservableCollection as property type. An ordinary `List<DependencyObject>` might work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are using a non-null default value for a dependency property that is of a mutable reference type.

All instances of your control are using the same default value, i.e. the same `ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>` instance, passed as default value by

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>())
```

---

You must not do it that way. Instead, use `null` as default value, or do not set a default value at all

```
internal static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(MenuItems),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>),
        typeof(OptionsMenu));
```

and assign an initial value in the control's constructor by `SetCurrentValue`, which in contrast to `SetValue` still allows to set other values by Style and Triggers Setters and similar sources:

```
public OptionsMenu()
{
    SetCurrentValue(MenuItemsProperty,
        new ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>());
}
```